# Mongos shard stats show all stats wrong, and on port 37017, when connected to port 27017

Tags: database, mongodb, sharding

My Mongo Shard service is sharded into 4 shards of equal size. I am able to connect to it correctly via the shell as well as Mongo Compass. 
I connect to the query service using the following command:

```
mongo MyServer-001:27017 -u <myusername> -p --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Next, I select the database that I have all my data in. However, once I run `db.stats()`, it shows four shards on port `37017`, with all but shard number 2 having stats with a `0` next to them, while shard 2 has this output for itself:

```
"MyServer-002:37017" : {
                        "db" : "WeatherData",
                        "collections" : 10,
                        "views" : 0,
                        "objects" : 199272873,
                        "avgObjSize" : 645.557547720005,
                        "dataSize" : 128642107221,
                        "storageSize" : 19373637632,
                        "numExtents" : 0,
                        "indexes" : 41,
                        "indexSize" : 6224769024,
                        "ok" : 1
                },
```

I am confused as to why data was migrated onto shard number 2 on port `37017`, when I myself established a link to shard one on port `27017` . I wasn't the one who configured mongodb on our servers, so just trying to understand why things haven't been put on shard one (the 'query service', as we were told by the sys admins)

What could the reason be for placing data on a different shard, and on a different port?

Comment: I'm confused. Can you post the output of `sh.status()`

Comment: Says I am not authorized to run that command once I run that in the mongos console